# Post request to not accessible domain

Tags: c#, ngrok

I need to send post request (using .net) to a public API, that is located on domain that is not accessible from my region.
Also I have a basic account ngrok.

How do I access the API in the VS2019, using ngrok (or using other tools)?

Comment: You will need to post it from a region that can access it.

Comment: I understand. I can watch the API through Tor, but I need to access from app

Comment: OK. I wish you all the best.